# Get postImage for two different steps - CRM - Plugin Registration

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, crm

I have registered plugin for CRM using Plugin Registration Tool.

I made two steps for that plugin. One is Update of `quotedetail` entity, the other one is Create of `quotedetail` entity.

Both entities have post Images called `postImage`.

Can i use:

`Entity postImage = context.PostEntityImages["postImage"];`

order to get the values of the fields, no meter weather entity is updated or created, or I need to give them different names and use separated orders for create and update?

If i have to, how do I check in the code which of this cases happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the code you've posted in both scenarios. You wouldn't need to differentiate them

Answer (score 1):

In order to check in the code whether its an Update or Create, you can use context.MessageName to get the name

If its an Update then context.MessageName will be "Update"
If its Create then context.MessageName will be "Create"